# Does attaching an address reveal its private key?

Tags: address-reuse, attach-to-tangle, private-key

So it is stated an outgoing transaction from an address would reveal some of the private key. That's why we don't reuse an address.

Technically address attaching is also a zero amount transaction. But does it reveal any part of the private key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, because when you attach an address, a zero-value transaction is done **to** the address. I.e. it's an incoming transaction to the target address and doesn't reveal the private key.